# How to pass data in flutter

Tags: php, flutter, barcode-scanner, inkscape

How  to pass data from php to get information, i try calling it but it show null in Flutter. First, I have a database and have code and also have php file to get infomation. I am using inkscape to create a barcode to scan it.

For example , I create barcode that contain 'P002',and databse also have the code. But i scan from it ,they show null in debug console Flutter.

This example from flutter ,i try to call

```
Future<Product> getProduct()async{
    await http.get("https://smileylion.com/easyshopping/php/getproduct.php?code=${widget.code}",)
        .then((response){
          if(jsonDecode(response.body)!=null){
            setState(() {
           product = Product.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
            });
            
          }
    });
    return product;
  }
```

My questions ,how to pass the data and not show null ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the API you use public? If that is the case, try consuming the endpoint you mentioned:

`https://smileylion.com/easyshopping/php/getproduct.php?code=POO2`

and this returns null, therefore it is a problem of the backend (database or services) not of flutter.

Comment: Hello ,i have try it in POSTMAN API is return info ,but i try to scan barcode "P002"in flutter they still cannot and return null . In this case is flutter or backend service problem ? How i can solve this?

Comment: The problem is in its Flutter function, because of how you have the function structured, what you want is for it to return a product, try this: `Future<Product> getProduct() async {
  final res = await http.get("https://smileylion.com/easyshopping/php/getproduct.php?code=${widget.code}");
  
  print(res.body) // To view data ... 
  
  if (res.body != null) {
    return Product.fromJson(jsonDecode(res.body));
  }
  
  return null;
}`

Comment: @leejiajia Make sure you have the correct model, you can use this application to create the models.

https://app.quicktype.io/

Comment: Hi i have to try this functions, it is works and return the information in the debug console  flutter. May i ask how to show the information on the app and not in debug console? is have any suggestions?

Comment: @leejiajia If you are working with a stateful widget you can declare a variable of type Product and initialize it.

I don't know where you are executing that function, but suppose you invoke it when this widget is rendered.

initState () {getProduct ()}

Now, you could modify the data type of the function to void, and follow the logic that already works, only now you must add a setState and within this assign the value that you receive from the request to the variable that you declared at the beginning.

Comment: I write this is below the that function(the url request) and then i write this code and the next is a widget and that i call information.
‘
@override
  void initState() {
  getProduct();
  print(product);
  super.initState();
 }
’and you says needs setstate? I write like this ...is correct?
` Future<Product> getProduct()async{
   final res = await http.get("https://smileylion.com/easyshopping/php/getproduct.php?code=${widget.code}");
  print(res.body);
  
if(res.body != null ){
  setState(() {
      return Product.fromJson(jsonDecode(res.body));
  });
}
    return null;
  }`

Comment: @leejiajia This is an example of what I mentioned, you must adapt it to your code.

https://justpaste.it/9gsw7

Another thing, the ideal is that you work with state managers such as: flutter_bloc, provider, get, river, redux, etc.

Comment: Very thanks you to help in the coding, i am a newbie in flutter and thanks you for the example . I will keep this example as my guide. Finally I come out the information.